# how to use transactions in F# using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, f#, transactions, stackexchange.redis

I'm looking for a simple F# example to do something like this:

```
db.StringSet(RedisKey.op_Implicit "a", RedisValue.op_Implicit "1") |> ignore
db.StringSet(RedisKey.op_Implicit "b", RedisValue.op_Implicit "2") |> ignore
```

but inside a transaction; I can't find any example doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The StackExchange.Redis client doesn't really have *transactions* in the traditional sense.  It has a slightly different feature that can be used for the same purposes.  You can read about it in their documentation [here](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Transactions.html).

In essence, you assert a pre-condition which must be true at the time of the operation for the operation to complete.  They have an `ITransaction` object on which you assert the conditions and attempt the operation, instead of acting directly on the database:

```ml
let key1 = RedisKey.op_Implicit "a"
let key2 = RedisKey.op_Implicit "b"
let value1 = RedisValue.op_Implicit "1"
let value2 = RedisValue.op_Implicit "2"

let transaction = db.CreateTransaction()
transaction.AddCondition(Condition.KeyNotExists(key1))
transaction.AddCondition(Condition.KeyNotExists(key2))

transaction.StringSetAsync(key1, value1) |> ignore
transaction.StringSetAsync(key2, value2) |> ignore

let committed = transaction.Execute()
```

You can then check whether the transaction was committed to see whether your keys were inserted or if the entire operation rolled back.